# How to instantiate View from ViewModel even if I don't want to display it right after?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I want to search through a few views' controls but I only have access to their ViewModels, because these views aren't displayed and there is no living instance of the view. 
Is there a way to instantiate a View through its ViewModel in code? I have to instantiate several of them in one place, having only the VM type. 
I'd like the code to be generic.

Edit - more specific information: 
I have a lot of different settings views. I want to search through them because right now, the user has to search manually - meaning the user has to go to every tab and look for the word he needs.
My VM is, of course, taking data from inputs but I am not interested in data - I'm interested in labels and texts which are shown to the user.

I'm using WPF, MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: If your using MVVM, the data that you're presenting in the views is normally in the ViewModel. In other words the state of the view is the vm. I'll not be surprised if you find a way to search inside the VMs

Comment: I have to get specific view's controls: labels, textbox and its contents. So VM isn't what I need :)

Comment: @Zerme give us more information what you wanna achieve. usually the view is just the representation for a VM. the view shouldnt have more information then the viewmodel

Comment: I have a lot of different settings views. I want to search through them because right now, the user has to search manually - meaning the user has to go to every tab and look for the word he needs. 
My VM is, of course, taking data from inputs but I am not interested in data - I'm interested in labels and texts which are shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. u need to understand that the views are also a class so u just need to create an object like any other class and when u call the ShowDialog. the method in view call it will display on UI

```
View MyView= new View();
ViewModel MyViewmodel= new ViewModel();
MyView.DataContext=MyViewmodel;
```

In this part of code it will create object of View and ViewModel and assign the dataContext Prop to Your Vm but not Displayed Any where.

```
List<View> AllView= new List<View>()
AllView.Add(MyView);
```

Here I saved your view in list. and these can be static or global. and whenever I need to access these, I will do

```
AllView[0].ShowDialog();
```

I'm displaying the first view. I think u got the idea. as per generic method u can check it create an object. it's not that hard. as per me it's not necessary.